# How to configure Rails 5 with webpack on AWS Fargate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, aws-fargate

I have a docker using rails 5 with react and I am using webpack for the js.

Can i run both rails and node.js (to handle react) on the same AWS task definition (i.e same docker inside Fargate) or do I need to split it in 2 AWS task definitions; One for rails and one for node.js?

I would prefer having everything onto one task definition but I am struggling to find example script for it.

I probably need to tune the webpacker.yml but can't find the right configuration.

Also i wondering how to manage the port 3000 from rails and 3035 from node

Did anybody went through similar case before? or try to do similar thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would recommend precompiling your assets in your Rails container, rather than running a dynamic node.js process to do this on the fly.

Something like:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

In your Dockerfile should work out.